# JavaScript | How to disable nagle algorithm without node.js

Tags: javascript, sockets, nagle

I'm trying to write a small client-server game. Server written in c++. Client on js.

For connection using websocket. Because highly depend on the delay I must disable nagle algorythm.

I know that in node.js you can do it using their setNoDelay() function. I need to do this in native javascript. Does anyone know how to do this and is it possible?

Comment: Where's the client running? In a browser? If so, you're out of luck. Browsers aren't going to let you fiddle with their sockets.

Comment: Yes, in browser. I have already copied to the flash client.